# Webservice in Metro app

Tags: json, web-services, soap, microsoft-metro

I'm doing my first app Metro Style. There was a big question. What better way to communicate my app with my service?

It would Json or Soap?

Does anyone have a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought WCF would be the most "modern" method of doing it. Soap would work as well though, I'm sure, if you're more familiar with that.